# I'm trying to create a react app in VSCode and get this error:

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

> error Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...a+1IZjq9w\na0Boou1XXP'

I've cleared the `npm-cache` and reinstalled `create-react-app` without error, but when I run this command:

```
npx create-react-app <app-name> --typescript
```

it throws the error above.

I can create a react app inside visual studio, but am following a reference that uses typescript.

Anyone else have this issue and found a solution for it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Other people in this thread seemed to have the same issue, but others had your problem still. Here is some steps that someone followed to get that working, I hope it works for you as well! https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/7261#issuecomment-638251186

Answer (score 0):

Try this if they work maybe

```
    npm cache clean --force

    npm update
```

Comment: That did'nt work. Running as admin and got this:  PS C:\Users\james\source\repos\QandA> npm cache clean --force
npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.
PS C:\Users\james\source\repos\QandA> npm update
PS C:\Users\james\source\repos\QandA> npx create-react-app frontend --typescript
npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ttrei\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-08-31T17_27_44_191Z-debug.log   
Install for [ 'create-react-app@latest' ] failed with code 1